# import external data to ONE simulator

Tags: bluetooth, simulator

I want to convert my `tracefile.txt` to standard format using as an imported trace file into ONE simulator. I have 3  "txt" file(UNICAL dataset downloaded from crawdad site:[www.crawdad.org](http://crawdad.org/all-byname.html)), a bluetooth contact file which is containing two nodeID and timestamps as below:

```
1   2   1390923561864-
1   2   1390925003119-
1   9   1391095406320-
1   9   1391096487223-
2   1   1391522133001-
2   1   1391526148381-
2   1   1391527769767-
2   1   1391529571307-
....
```

The second file contains friendships between nodes (if two nodes are friends =1 else =0), and the third file :"Interests", which is a weighted adjacency matrix,Although, I know I can have a graphviz report from my result in ONE simulator, is it possible to use this report as an imported data in ONE simulator? if yes, how can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Process the dataset**

Wirte a script (`awk`, `python`, or something else) to convert the dataset to meet The ONE's requirement, i.e., each line like `time CONN node_i node_j up/down`, for instance:

```
21574 CONN 1 40 up
21687 CONN 1 40 down
```

**Step 2: Import to The ONE simulator**

Configure your settings file, the main items are as follows:

```
Scenario.simulateConnections = false
Group.movementModel = StationaryMovement
Group.nodeLocation = 0,1

Events.nrof = 2
Events1.class = ExternalEventsQueue
Events1.filePath = path/infocom05.txt
```